# Recommended way to override a method on a constrained extension in swift, avoiding message "Ambiguous use of 'xxx'"

Tags: swift, inheritance, compiler-errors

I know why I'm having the error message, so the question is more about what is in Swift 2.x times, the recommended way to go about this.

The data I want to represent is conceptually nothing more than an `Array` of a specialized class/struct, with some extra methods that semantically only make sense for that particular kind of elements.

Swift gives us *constrained extensions*, which are great for this.

To make my problem concrete, let's say I want a deck of cards.  So for `Card` I can define a protocol that allows me to make a constrained extension on `Array`

```
// Define a protocol for specializing Arrays of Cards
protocol _CardType {}
extension Card: _CardType {}
```

And then

```
typealias Deck = [Card]

extension Array where Element : _CardType {
}
```

Inside that extension, I can define all the functionality that I want related to the deck of cards, say shuffling, cutting, or whatever.

I could also inside that extension, write something like

```
    var description: String {
      return "Deck: " + self.map { "\($0)" }.joinWithSeparator(",")
    }
```

This would be nice and good until I try at some point to write somewhere else

```
  func showDeck() {
    print(deck.description)
  }
```

This will not even compile, getting the message

> Ambiguous use of 'description'

Of course, I managed here to have Array's version of description and my extension's version, and at this point the compiler can't tell which is the correct one.

I can't hint with the `override` keyword.  If I tried to use it on the extension, I'd get the message

> Property does not override any property of its superclass

Easy solutions on this made-up scenario would be to define for `Deck` a different function `prettyDescription`, so one wouldn't have to try to override description, or to use a 'has-a' model instead of a 'is-a' model (i.e.) `Deck` would have a property with the array of cards.

The point is that I want to take advantage of pre-existing code outside my class, where there is already functionality that expects a 'is-a' relationship (in this case, having a `description`).

In the made-up scenario, the `description` function is the standard way an `Array` gets printed out, so I want `Deck` to conform.

Happy to hear thoughts on the best way to approach this.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Please provide sufficient code to allow me to copy your code into a project, try to compile it, and get your error. (On the surface, the issue looks like a problem with `deck` in `deck.description`, which is not defined in the context you've shown it, so it's impossible to say what it might be.)

Comment: There may be specific reasons for not doing so, but have you thought about making `Card` a class that inherits from `CardType` ? Also, the reason you can't `override` is that you aren't subclassing anything.
Finally, and this a more fundamental issue, what you are doing isn't necessarily a very good way to do it. 

I would recommend creating a `CardType` protocol, a `Card` struct or class that inherits from `CardType`, and finally a wrapper around `Deck`, e.g. a class where an instance variable is an `Array<Card>` or `Array<CardType>`. Conform to `CustomStringConvertible` and you'll be good

Comment: Thanks @matt.  Here I just uploaded a gist that would reproduce: https://gist.github.com/jcmendez/442ef92be9358a9eab256275c254c54e

Comment: But that won't compile, will it? You haven't defined `simpleDescription` anywhere, you don't import the app target module into the test... It makes no sense.

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne - the only reason to use the `_CardType` protocol is because in the given example, `Card` is a simple struct, and from Apple's documentation, "You write type constraint by placing a single class or protocol constraint after a type parameter's name, separated by a colon, as part of the type parameter list.".  Since strict is not a class nor a protocol, I needed to do that workaround.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMéndez I recently ended up rewriting a lot of code because we decided to change the basic types. I see what you mean but it might be wise to consider using different basic types. Of course, I don't know anything about your code---but do consider it.

Comment: @matt - I typed that up on the gist as an example.  Assuming that `Rank` has a method `simpleDescription` that would return the string for the card rank (A,2,3,...,J,Q,K), and `Suit` has also a method `simpleDescription` with the string for the suit (♣,♠,...)

Comment: What's needed is not "an example" but a reproducible case. However, by modifying sufficiently, I was able to reproduce well enough. Thanks.

Comment: "where there is already functionality that expects a 'is-a' relationship (in this case, having a description)" But, if that's all you want, then, as you've already been told, make a completely different Deck struct and adopt CustomStringConvertible. That is exactly what it is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can't do it with extension, from Apple docs:

> Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality

For overriding existing functionality you need to use a superClass.

Comment: You are correct, from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html  -  This is why I end up getting the "Ambiguous use of 'description'" error.  I'm trying to understand how would people go about this usage of constrained extensions.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMéndez It doesn't matter if this is constrained extension, the behaviour is the same, you just can't do it, use a different method name in your extension, or a super class. I agree that it would be nice if this would be possible

Comment: @JuanCarlosMéndez Seems like you can in 3.1: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift3-1

Comment: @JuanCarlosMéndez Still can't override existing functionality - https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151.

Answer (score 2):

> The data I want to represent is conceptually nothing more than an Array of a specialized class/struct, with some extra methods that semantically only make sense for that particular kind of elements.
>
> Swift gives us constrained extensions, which are great for this

No, they are not; that is not at all what they are for. That's why you're having troubles; your premises are fatally flawed, so what follows from them is untenable.

Let's look at the details of what your attempt to do this has come up against.

- Swift Array already implements `description`. Deck is merely an Array. You cannot reimplement its existing `description` in an extension. The surprise here is only that your attempt to do so compiles in the first place; I'd call that a bug, though I could be wrong about that.
- You are also hampered here by the fact that Array in Swift is a struct, not a class. (That is why you can't "override" `description`; there is no such thing as "override" where a struct is concerned, as there is no inheritance.)

Basically, then, your whole architecture of trying to use an extension to make Deck be a "kind of Array" is misguided.

I would suggest that instead of trying to use an "is-a" relationship between Deck and Array, you use a "has-a" relationship; make a Deck into something that *has* an array of cards (as a property) and that adopts CustomStringConvertible and (therefore) implements a `description` property. That will solve the problem nicely.

Comment: I agree @matt that is strange it compiles, and I know the example is somewhat contrived.  The idea of using a "has-a" would work for the Deck example.  However, the key point on the original question is that because of all the other classes around my software, I would strongly prefer an "is-a" instead of "has-a".  Will edit the question because your clarification is very helpful

Comment: I don't think I'm making myself clear. It really doesn't matter what you prefer. There is no "is-a" with structs, and trying to use extensions to pretend there is won't work.

Comment: I agree with @matt. 
@JuanCarlosMéndez, you say you 'strongly prefer' one approach, but as I said in another comment, you are running against the wall with that approach. In this case, you should create a class or struct representing representing your `Deck` that holds an array of your cards. Implement `CustomStringConvertible`.